# JFree chart set axis to percentage

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want my Axis in my [JFree charts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to become % instead of normal numbers does anyone know how I can modify my code so this happens.

It should be said that my table is already in procentage but the graph it self is not!

**UPDATE**

This is what ive tried so far yet still no changes:

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    DecimalFormat pctFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0%");
    rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(pctFormat); 
    rangeAxis.setRange(0.0, 100.0);

    chart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
    title = periode;
    chartPanel.setChart(chart);
    setTableModel(true,true);
```

**UPDATE2**

To set the intervals to 10 you need the following code:

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setRange(0.0, 100.0);
        rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NumberAxis#setNumberFormatOverride()` and provie a `java.text.NumberFormat`

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot(); 
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
DecimalFormat pctFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0%");
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(pctFormat);
```

Comment: ive tried the following:
 NumberAxis plots = new NumberAxis();
 DecimalFormat procentage = new DecimalFormat("##0.0");

yet that did not change the chart?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen you are missing a "%" from your `DecimalFormat`

Comment: Thank you for your help but my chart still goes from 0 - 105 is there anyway i can change this aswell? :S and is it possible top change the intervals to 10% pr line (so it goes 0 10 20 30 40 ect)

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Yes to both your questions but it is impossible to tell you how without access to **your** code.  For example is 105 105% or 10500%? What sort of Chart are you using? My answer may be different for a `CategoryPlot` or and `XYPlot`.  If you add your code in the form of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) we can help further

Comment: it is a StackedBarChart and a LineChart and i am sorry i am unable to add it to a SSCCEE basicly because the code is so INSANELY messy and collecting all its data from a database. :S

Comment: Ive just found something new in my friends code: 

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
  rangeAxis.setRange(0.0, 100.0);
  rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
  rangeAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true);

Comment: All i need now is to change its range into 10, 20 ,30 ect.